# using string value of a processing instruction in the use attribute of <xsl:key>

Tags: xml, xslt, key

Hello I am trying to get the value of a pseudo attribute in a processing instruction and put the value of that pseudo attribute into a key value for each instance of that processing instruction.

So an example of the processing instructions looks like this in the xml content:

```
<?uspc-assoc-workflow sws='C139995_131101' forum='2014/12' target='9S1' type='PCA'?>
```

An example of my  template is below. I have only seen instances of the  template using an actual attribute but since this is a processing instruction I can't simply use @sws as the value so I have tried to capture the value of the pseudo attribute in the string by using this:

```
<xsl:key name="uspcassocworkflow" match="processing-instruction('uspc-assoc-workflow')" use="substring-before(substring-after(., 'sws=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
```

Is this code above valid?

I have a second set of processing instruction called uspc-end-add that look like this:

```
<?uspc-end-add id='f104450-r0001'  sws='C139995_131101'  symbols='yes'?>
```

and a template to match it that looks like this:

```
   <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('uspc-end-add')" name="end_add">
  <!-- Need to be able to get the key values of the uspc-assoc-workflow sws psudo attribute here below -->
    <xsl:for-each select="key('uspcassocworkflow', '@sws')">
    <!-- Then here I need to be able test if the variable value endswsnumber matches one of uspassocworkflow processing instructions key value -->
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'id=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="endswsnumber"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'sws=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="symbol"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'symbol=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/></xsl:variable>
```

So above I am trying to bring those key values to this template and then I want to test if the variable endswsnumber is match to one of the key values of the uspc-assoc-workflow PI. If they are a match and once I have the corresponding uspc-assoc-workflow PI. I will do a test for what the value is in the that corresponding uspc-assoc-workflow psudo attribute is for "target" and output a different span for each target value. So if the target value of that corresponding uspc-assoc-workflow is '9S1' as in the example above I will output one span html vs outputting a different span in the html if the value is '9S2'. There are only a few different values for the "target" psudo attribute so I do a test for each one.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't use `@sws` either way! You got to consider it as a string. Also, single quote is represented using `&apos;` and not using `&quot;`(which is for double quotes). Can you minimize your question to have only one expected output with complete XSLT, and we can update it so that the output is achieved.

Comment: Could I use <xsl:for-each select="key('uspcassocworkflow', 'substring-before(substring-after(., &quot;sws=&apos;&quot;), &quot;&apos;&quot;)')"> and match that value after 'sws=' and before the closing " ' " to the same corresponding value in a uspc-end-add PI without knowing the value of the actual string beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below example will direct you right:

To select the processing-instruction in the below input XML:

```
<root>
    <?uspc-assoc-workflow sws='C139995_131101' forum='2014/12' target='9S1' type='PCA'?>
</root>
```

You can use the following stylesheet that uses the value `C139995_131101` in key to select the PI:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="uspcassocworkflow" match="processing-instruction('uspc-assoc-workflow')" use="substring-before(substring-after(., &quot;sws=&apos;&quot;), &quot;&apos;&quot;)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('uspcassocworkflow', 'C139995_131101')"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Giving the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output><?uspc-assoc-workflow sws='C139995_131101' forum='2014/12' target='9S1' type='PCA'?></output>
```

Here, the key finds the PI `uspc-assoc-workflow` that has `C139995_131101` as the substring after `sws='` and before `'`.

[check it out here](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5U)

Comment: Hello Lingamurthy, thanks for the quick reply. But instead of using the actual value and specifying which key I want (in this case C139995_131101) I want to be able to use the value of the 'sws' psudo attribute that matches the uspc-add-end PI psudo attribute for 'sws' as a variable. There will be multiple uspc-assoc-workflow PIs and multiple uspc-add-end PIs and I don't know beforehand what there 'sws' value are going to be other than that they each have a corresponding matching 'sws' value. So is it possible to make in your example 'C139995_131101' into a matching variable value?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to one of the commercial editions of Saxon 9 then consider to use the extension function `saxon:get-pseudo-attribute` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/get-pseudo-attribute.html) it provides:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="saxon">

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('uspc-assoc-workflow')">
        <xsl:variable name="sws" select="saxon:get-pseudo-attribute('sws')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$sws"/>        
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```